# I have a combo box in my form, and I want that each time test case runs selenium ide picks a value randomly from combo box list

Tags: selenium, combobox

I have a combo box in my form, and I want each time the test case runs that selenium ide picks a random value from the combo box list.

In selenium I have this:

```
Command: store
Target: javascript{Math.floor(Math.random())}
Value: man
```

and in next step:

```
Command: select
Target: id of combo box
Value: ${man}
```

But when I run the test case; it generates an error:

> '[error] Option with label '0' not found'.

How can I accomplish this task.

Comment: Too little details... How many possibilities are there? And btw: That function you posted here will return you 0 or 1. And I am almost sure that most of the times it will be 0

Comment: Yes it is giving me '0' all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Your java script code is giving result as 0 all the time.There is a slight change required for your java script to work. Use the following code,

**Command:** store **Target:** javascript{Math.floor(Math.random()*3)} **Value:** man

This will give a random value between 0 to 2 on every run.Value 3 used in the formula is a variable, it stands for the count of items in the ComboBox. If you have 6 items in your ComboBox then you will have to replace 3 with 6.

next line is to select a ComboBox item based on id value,

**Command:** select **Target:** css=select **Value:** id=${man}

However there is a catch, in-order for this to work there should be an id attribute in all the tags with incremental numeric value 0,1,2,..etc.

For instance,

```
<select>
  <option id="0">Milk</option>
  <option id="1">Tea</option>
  <option id="2">Coffee</option>
</select>
```

Or else for it to work with the way you have written i.e,

**Command:** select **Target:** css=select **Value:** ${man}

then ComboBox should have values incremental from 0,1,2,3, etc. For instance the HTML code will be like,

```
<select>
  <option>0</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
```

---

#### Updates

---

As per your latest response I have modified the formula and it works,

**Command:** storeEval **Target:** {var myList=new Array(111,222,333,444,888,999,555,777,221,"ADA","AD");  myList[Math.floor(Math.random()*11)]} **Value:** myListVal

**Command:** select **Target:** css=select **Value:** ${myListVal}

**Details**

{var myList=new Array(111,222,333,444,888,999,555,777,221,"ADA","AD");  myList[Math.floor(Math.random()*11)]}

1. Created an Array **myList** and stored it with values you wanted in your list.
2. As there 11 list items, I created a formula Math.floor(Math.random()*11) which will randomly generate values from 0 to 10.
3. When executed from Selenium-IDE,**myList** array will have randomly changing index values from 0 to 10. And it will result in varying array values for myList stored to variable **myListVal**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply CheryJose. But I am still getting the same error. Values in option list are like this:                                                        <option value="0">-- Please Select --</option>
  <option value="477">111</option>
  <option value="103">222</option>
  <option value="460">333</option>
  <option value="476">999</option>
  <option value="475">444</option>
  <option value="478">888</option>
  <option value="471">555</option>
  <option value="127">777</option>
  <option value="120">221</option>
  <option value="101">ADA</option>
  <option value="99">AD</option>

Comment: I have got solution for your requirement, I have updated the answer with the details.

Comment: I implement it like you suggested but now I am stuck with some new error; don't know why it is generating it: Command :storeEval Target: javascript (var myList=new Array(111, "3COM", 6080, 999, "A9211", "aas", "ACER", "ACTIONTEC", "ADAPTEC", "ADDONICS", "AIPTEK"); myList[Math.floor(Math.random()*11)]) Value: my ListVal. but now im getting this error continuously: '[error] Threw an exception: syntax error'